# ImportError while importing pandas: gettz not built

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, importerror

Suddenly my python file won't run anymore due to an ImportError. I already tried updating/reinstalling pandas via conda but this didn't change anything.

```
  File "/p/tmp/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
  File "/p/tmp/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "/p/tmp/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .conversion import OutOfBoundsTimedelta, localize_pydatetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx", line 7, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones
ImportError: cannot import name gettz

srun: error: cs-g14c06b11: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
srun: Terminating job step 19094047.0
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/p/tmp/user/file_name.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd 
  File "/p/tmp/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    ) from e
ImportError: C extension: gettz not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

What could I try to fix this?

Comment: it seems it use C/C++ code and it may need compiler for this.

Comment: @furas And how can I fix this? It runs on a cluster not on my local machine.

Comment: error shows `"you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first."` - so maybe you wll have to do it - or you may have to ask admins to do it.

Comment: @furas In which directory do I need to run this command?

Comment: I don't know - as I know you may have `setup.py` in module only if you download as source code. But when you install it with `pip` then you get without source code and `setup.py` so it can be useless. BUT I see function `gettz` in module [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) and maybe it need to install `dateutil` before installing `pandas` and it will compile it.

Comment: @furas Yes installing ```dateutil``` fixed the error, very weird. Thanks!

Comment: `pandas` may use many external modules (ie. `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `dateutil`, `csv`, `xlsreader`, `lxml`, `requests`) and normally it should install all of them automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by furas, installing the package `dateutil` fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

step1: run `pip uninstall pandas`

step2: run `pip install python-dateutil`

step3: run `pip install pandas`

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problems with Karthic Srinivasan's method, but I meet another problems when install `pandas`. My solution is open `cmd` authorized, and using `conda` replacing `pip` to install `pandas`, that solve this problem.